# Allow Meteor Accounts to have multiple users with the same email address

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm building a Meteor app where I don't care if two people have the same email address because I'm using the username as login key.

I've been searching for a way to setup Meteor Accounts (accounts-password) to make this possible but I couldn't find any resource.

Is it even possible ? Should I roll my own registration mechanism just for that small difference ?

Comment: just don't ask for the email address? http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_ui_config USERNAME_ONLY

Comment: @ChristianFritz This allows for email to be null for still not multiple users to have the same address.

Answer (score 2):

In account-base.js, this index is set

```
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('emails.address', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
```

This is what set the behaviour. We need to drop that index. Looking at the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/), i see that

```
Meteor.users._dropIndex({"emails.address": 1});
```

will do the trick, BUT, I am new i Meteor, so I don't know where to put this and if this is the best approach.

I put it in a server file and it worked fine... but research more